# How to index CouchDB with Elastic Search River: In plain english

Tags: couchdb, elasticsearch

I really don't know what's going on with my configuration, but I'm just not able to query anything after indexing (don't even know if I'm doing the indexing part correctly).  Could someone please tell me what each of the following means and should be?

I have a CouchDB database called `bestdb`. Inside this database I have document types like `product` and `customer`.

Now I installed elastic search version 0.18.7 and the corresponding couchdb river.  I started elastic search and couchdb.  I set the network.host of elasticsearch to be an ip address:  10.0.0.129 .  I followed the instructions in the [tutorial](http://www.elasticsearch.org/tutorials/2010/08/01/couchb-integration.html) :

```
curl -XPUT '10.0.0.129:9200/_river/{A}/_meta' -d '{
    "type" : "couchdb",
    "couchdb" : {
        "host" : "localhost",
        "port" : 5984,
        "db" : "bestdb",
        "filter": null
    },
    "index" : {
        "index" : "{B}",
        "type" : "{C}",
        "bulk_size" : "100",
        "bulk_timeout" : "10ms"
    }
}'
```

{A}:  What's this? My understanding is that this is just an internal elastic search index right?  It's not being used for querying or searching right? So this could be any name right?

{B}:  What's this index?  How is this different from the one above?  What should the value of this be in my scenario?

{C}:  Is this related to the Document Type in couchdb, like `product` or `customer` ?

The online tutorial just sets everything to be the same value.  How would my curl statement look like if I wanted to query all product documents or customer documents?

Thank you to whoever that clears things up a bit for me.

Regards,
Mark Huang

Answer (score 1, accepted):

kimchy's documentation often leaves a little bit to the imagination. :-)

**A** is the river name.  A river is just an ES document, stored in an index named `_river`, a type named whatever you want, and a doc id `_meta`.

**B** & **C** is the local `index/_type` that your `bestdb` couchdb _changes stream will get indexed into.  These can be overridden by `_index` and `_type` fields in your couchdb documents.  If none of the above is supplied, they'll default to your couchdb instance name `bestdb/bestdb`.

Comment: Thank you for responding, really appreciate it.  Can you explain to me using the context I've provided; product document type?  What would _index and _type fields generally be?  In my case, would _index (or from the above example {B}) be the product ID AND _type be "product"?

Comment: If I don't add the index object, how do I query my couchdb instance?

Comment: I'm a little bit unfamiliar with how couchdb works, but from the ES code, if the docs from your `_changes` stream have `_index` and `_type` fields those will override the default in the river settings. So, you can set a sensible defaults for **B** and **C** in the settings, but to separate product/customer docs for your business logic it looks like you'll have to do some of the work in your couchdb docs.